# GWT How to Layout Widgets within a Panel using CSS

Tags: java, css, gwt

I have two labels, two datepickers, and a submit button within a DockLayoutPanel.  I'm trying to just get the button to show up in the center of the panel.

Here is the code I am trying to get just to get the button centered:

```
    Button b = new Button("Submit", new ClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(Widget sender)
        {
            getAwards(text.getText(),text2.getText());
        }
    });
    b.setWidth("80px");
    b.addStyleName("gwt-Button");
```

and within my css:

```
.gwt-Button{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

What edits or method do I have to take to actually get this to work?

Edit: For extra information, this button is being added to a DockLayoutPanel

Comment: Are you sure the css is actual set, because if I test it on a button added to a DockLayoutPanel is works fine. Or maybe show how you use the button on the DockLayoutPanel. Further, `gwt-button` is the default styleName for a gwt button so why do you add it? And, don't use `ClickListener` it's been deprecated, use `ClickHandler`.

Comment: Why are you setting the style name of the Button to the default GWT name in your code? It's a GWT class, it will have its class set to gwt-Button without you doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.gwt-Button{
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left: -40px; /* Width Button /2 */
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to see a little more explanation in this.

Comment: I mean literally nothing changed, the new CSS behaved identically to the previous CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the loading of whatever default GWT theme you are using (such as clean) in your gwt.xml file, it may be messing with things, since you're using the same class name.

Alternatively, just use a CSS class name other than "gwt-Button" here.